# Чтение вывода консоли другой программы

Tags: c#, windows, консоль, вывод, ввод

У меня есть игровой сервер, доступа к исходному коду к которого у меня нет. Он выводит логи в консоль при подключении игрока. Я хочу читать эти логи, а потом как-нибудь их обрабатывать. Пишу на c#. Сервер тоже на с#, но я хотел бы узнать универсальный способ.
Как это можно сделать? (на Винде)

Comment: Запускайте программу с перенаправлением вывода в файл: `server.exe > log.txt`. Всё.

Comment: Допишите код сервера так, чтобы он параллельно писал в лог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передача вывода одной программы на ввод другой осуществляется с помощью оператора `|`:

```
program1.exe | program2.exe
```

Всё, что `program1.exe` выводит в консоль, будет перенаправлено в консольный ввод `program2.exe`